# Macro that exports a single row to a new sheet without overwriting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so the title says pretty much everything.
I have a dynamic row with dropdowns, formulas, etc and I want to export the values of that row to a new sheet, without overwriting the previous exported row, which I managed to do (overwriting). So I'd make the macro, use it, and it would just paste values all over the previous export. Can anyone help me with this? This is my macro btw, in case someone needs it.

```
function Export2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:J2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TVDB'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('TV!A2:J2').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You are copying to `spreadsheet.getActiveRange()` - this means to the actively selected range

If you want to copy to the first empty row, you need to modify your code using the Apps Script method [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

**Important:**

When using the method `getLastRow()`, and copying sheets in general, it is recommended that you apply the methods to a chosen `sheet`, rather than `spreadsheet` in order to avoid problems.

**Sample:**

```js
function Export2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var originSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("TV");
  var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TVDB');
  var lastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
  originSheet.getRange('A2:J2').copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(lastRow +1, 1), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};
```

I recommend you to invest some time to review the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) in order to get a better understanding of the code and being able to modify it if needed. Mind that recording macros mostly does not result in the most efficient and elegant code.